# PHP fopen variable instead of string

Tags: php, fopen, glob

I'm currently trying to make my script dynamic and looking for a way to grab my file data with wildcards.

This is my old code:

```
#process .csv into the database
if(($handle = fopen("9_filename.csv", "r")))
```

Here I just grab a file through a string. Works fine. But it's static and I need to process 20 files per week at once, which change the calendar week in the file name.

So after some research I found the "glob" function, which allows me to set wildcards. So I assign a variable with the "glob" function. A var_dump returns the correct file name "9_filename.csv". So the string exists.

This is my new code:

```
#variables
$file = glob("*_filename.csv");

#process .csv into the database
if(($handle = fopen($file, "r")))
```

Unfortunately as a result I get the following error:

> Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given
>   in

Comment: Since `glob` may match more than one file, it'll return an *array* of files (even if that array is only `1` long)…

Comment: You need to iterate over the array one-by one like this:- `$file = glob("*_filename.csv");

foreach($file as $fil){
 if(($handle = fopen($file, "r")))
 .......rest code
}`

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)? It explicitly says the return value is an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `glob` finds *all files matching pattern*, it must return an array.
And fopen can only handle one at a time, so you need to feed them one at a time:

```
#variables
$files = glob("*_filename.csv");

foreach($files as $file){
    #process .csv into the database
    if(($handle = fopen($file, "r")))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`glob()` functions return an array of filenames or directories matching a specified pattern.
So once you get an array you need to loop through each array.
In that case you can then use

`if(($handle = fopen("9_filename.csv", "r")))`

where `9_filename.csv` will be one the array value.